# ActionView/Spinner with match_parent in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I need spinner in Action Bar for filtering content, looking something similar to this:

[image]

But spinner should fill full length of action bar.

What i tried:

1)  `actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(navigationAdapter, this);`

Yes, it works. But i need this filter only in 1 fragment. Yes, i can use `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` only in this fragment, and change it to `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD` in others. But if i will want to add differenat filter in another fragment. So, i should to setting type, adapter and etc in every fragment. It's very very awfully.

2) Better solution is to use menu. In `onCreateOptionsMenu` of fragment i can add item with `actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"` only in fragment where i need this. Almost good solution except that this item will align right and doesn't fill full action bar.

**So, my question is**: how to make menu item fill full action bat length?
Or can you advise better solution?

Btw, `setCustomView` for ActionBar - bad solution for the same reasons that `setListNavigationCallbacks`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. You should user your own layout for spinner item.

Instead of:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.projects_filteres, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Use:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), R.layout.projects_filter_item, 
                android.R.id.text1, getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.projects_filteres));
```

Where `R.array.projects_filteres` - just simple array from resources, and `R.layout.projects_filter_item` is `RelativeLayout` with     `android:layout_width="match_parent"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, whole code of `onCreateOptionsMenu` in fragment looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_context_menu, menu);

    android.view.MenuItem filter = menu.findItem(R.id.context_menu_filter);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), R.layout.projects_filter_item, 
            android.R.id.text1, getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.projects_filteres));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)MenuItemCompat.getActionView( filter);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });

}
```